# Create subsets by group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Here I have a data of three fields Dealer,Product,Freq.
My aim is to create a data which will contain top 2 sells for each dealer.

I have done it using data.table as bellow:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(Dealer = c("A","B","A","A","B","A"),
                 Product = c("a","b","b","c","d","d"),
                 Freq = c(10,12,23,24,23,12))

dt[,.SD[order(Freq, decreasing = T)][seq_along(Freq) < 3], by = Dealer]
```

How to do the similar thing using 'dplyr' package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I group by `Dealer` then find the top 2 values of `Freq` in each group.

```
dt %>% group_by(Dealer) %>% top_n(2, Freq) %>% ungroup

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Dealer Product  Freq
#   <fct>  <fct>   <dbl>
# 1 B      b          12
# 2 A      b          23
# 3 A      c          24
# 4 B      d          23
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice` or `filter` after doing the `group_by` and `arrange` (same methodology as in the OP's post)

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(Dealer) %>% 
   arrange(Dealer, desc(Freq)) %>%
   slice(1:2) 
   # or with 
   # filter(row_number() < 3)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Dealer [2]
#  Dealer Product  Freq
#  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 A      c          24
#2 A      b          23
#3 B      d          23
#4 B      b          12
```

NOTE: In case of ties, this will get the output exactly the number of rows specified in the `slice` or `filter`